# How can I optimise a foreach calling an API? The code calls an API and returns the first string reponse

Tags: c#, api

I have the following code that makes a call to an external API, processes the response and returns a string. The problem is it is taking a very long time to process. I can't do anything to the API, but I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing the rest of the code.

```
foreach(var item in products)
{
    item.site = await _testRepo.GetSiteLink(item.Id, item.baseLink);
}
```

And the GetSiteLink method in a different class.

```
public async Task<string> GetSiteLink(int itemId, string baseLink)
{
    var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseLink);
    var response = await _client.GetAsync($"apilink/{itemId}/?ulp={encodedUrl}");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(responseContent);
        return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parsedResponse[0]);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: `IDisposable`: `using var response = await ...`. It would allow to reuse the opened server connections faster.

Comment: Also answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17096201/12888024) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

one way of solving this would be using `Task.WhenAll` the idea is to add all tasks into a list of tasks then we call `Task.WhenAll` and await the final results.

Here is an example of it :

```
private async Task<ProductItem> SetSiteLink(ProductItem item)
{   
    item.site = await _testRepo.GetSiteLink(item.Id, item.baseLink); 
    
    return Task.FromResult(item);  
}
```

then call it like this :

```
var tasks = new List<Task<ProductItem>>();

foreach (var item in products)
{
    tasks.Add(SetSiteLink(item));
}

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the `products` and overloadness of the downstream system this approach could make the situation even worse. Instead of issuing a single request against a service which is already struggling you issue N requests. The chance of failure (or timeout) might increase with this approach. I would suggest this approach only with throttling.